# Cyberduck limits itself to 5 connections with "Maximum allowed connections exceeded"

Tags: openstack, cyberduck

I'm uploading multiple files to SWIFT (Softlayer ObjectStorage) using CyberDuck. Cyberduck limits itself to 5 active uploads at a time and queues the rest.

The other uploads are listed as "Maximum allowed connections exceeded. Waiting..."

What determines this limit? Is it set in CyberDuck, in my operating system (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard), or in the remote host?

Is there any way for me to increase the maximum number of allowed connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Cyberduck Help / Howto / File Transfers](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/transfer) the maximum allowed concurrent transfers can be limited using the toggle in the lower right of the transfer window:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The spinner seems to max out 9, though. I'll have to investigate if there's a way to get it past 9.